# gulp - do i have to install plugins for every project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I have a question about gulp.

I understand that when i want to use gulp with my project I need to run "npm init" for package json, I need to install gulp locally (assuming globally is already installed) with "npm install --save-dev gulp" and i need to install all the plugins i want to use (--save-dev so locally?). Im using about 10 gulp plugins and thats about 300mb+ of download (i dont understand why) for every project. Also the download is taking way too much time.

My question is: do i have to install all plugins for every new project i want to run with gulp? Or can i just copy gulp file and run it without installing plugins all over again because it takes 30 minutes to install them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You basically have these options:

```
npm install pkg           // install package locally
npm install -g pkg        // install globally
npm install pkg --save    // install package locally and save to package.json
npm install -g pkg --save // install package globally and save to package.json
```

Comment: But what about plugins? Im more concerned about them then installing gulp

Comment: What plugins do you mean?

Comment: npm install --save-dev gulp-less gulp-autoprefixer gulp-minify-css gulp-concat gulp-uglyfly gulp-image-optimization
Do I have to run this command for every project. It takes 30min to execute it and it installs 300+ mb of files

Comment: Also, I exchanged "gulp" with *pkg*

Comment: Add -g and everything is installed globally. If you want just a single packages global, simply run `npm` twice

Comment: npm install -g <plugins> ?  This will install plugins globally and i dont have to install them for every single project? Is there effect on gulp if I use them like this? Why in ever docs of plugin they put the --save-dev ?

Comment: They do it, because they suggest adding these packages to the dependencies. This means, installing the whole thing on a differen machine is easy. If you choose to do so globally, that doesn't affect the dependency status. It just means there not saved in the project. If you'll never move your code to a different machine, you don't need `--save` at all.

Comment: For example you develop many gulp projects, you want to install the packages globally. But you still `--save` them to allow `npm` the local installation during deployment on the production machine.

Comment: `-g` and `--save` are two completely different things, you use them independently. And no, it will have no effect on anything. When you use `require()`, node will look in the global module directory, then in the projects module_dir.

Comment: You're welcome! And as always, please don't forget to accept ;-)